# Is there a term in English (or any other language) to refer to the movement of a large, rapidly spreading fire?

Tags: terminology

I like very specific words and this would help me with a poem I'm writing. Also, if you have any references for very specific words/know any yourself (English or otherwise), they would be appreciated. (:

Comment: Wildfire......?

Answer (score 1):

I think [conflagration](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conflagration) would work for this.

> con·fla·gra·tion noun \ˌkän-flə-ˈgrā-shən\
>   : a large destructive fire

Answer (score 1):

'Holocaust' also comes to mind although it is a heavily laden term , meaning 'burnt whole' and 'thorough destruction by fire.' From your description it's hard to beat 'conflagration' or 'wildfire'--their only down-side is that they are so familiar.

Answer (score 1):

You could call your fire a *[three-alarmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-alarm_fire)*:-

> One-alarm, two-alarm, three-alarm fires, or higher, are categories of
>   fires indicating the level of response by local authorities, with an
>   elevated number of alarms indicating increased commitment of
>   resources.

This would have the advantage that it has already appeared (or not) in [poetry](http://wonderingminstrels.blogspot.com/2002/08/lama-ogden-nash.html):-

> The one L lama, he's a priest
>
> The two L llama, he's a beast
>
> And I will bet my silk pyjama
>
> There isn't any three L lllama.

(Ogden Nash) Some publications have his footnote:-

> *The author's attention has been called to a type of conflagration known as a three-alarmer. Pooh.